# Facebook Graph Api me/accounts endpoint returns error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, fb-graph

I made a request to the fb graph api using me/accounts endpoint. What should I do?

I changed version (v19.0). [https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/me/accounts?access_token=${access_token}](https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/me/accounts?access_token=$%7Baccess_token%7D) it returns
"error": {
"message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (accounts) on node type (Page)",
"type": "OAuthException",
"code": 100,
"fbtrace_id": "AaGw1Io8UvQ5GtprNlLcP4g"
}
}

Comment: _"What should I do?"_ - use the correct type of access token. You obviously used a page access token here, but pages don't have "accounts" - users do.

Comment: Which endpoint should I use to return accounts?

Comment: You can _keep_ using that one. You just have to use it with the correct type of token.